# SignalR Application with Remote SQL Server ScaleOut not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, signalr

I am developing an ASP.NET SignalR application with SQL Server scaleout and `SqlDependency`. My  asp.net application is hosted in local IIS and SQL Server is on a remote server. When I test the application hosted on my local machine's IIS and connecting to my "local machine" database the application works fine.

But when I try my application hosted on my local IIS connecting to the remote SQL Server, notification from SQL Server is not being sent to my application and my page is not refreshing for a change in the SQL Server table.

SQL Server is reachable from my application as for the first time when I load the application, it retrieves all records from SQL Server and displays on the page. But when I make a change to the SQL Server table (inserting a new row), notification of that change does not reach my page to refresh the newly added row on the page.

I am trying to access the remote SQL Server through a VPN network. Is there any problem connecting a SignalR application through VPN network? Or what can be other reasons for my application not working when connecting to remote SQL Server?

Comment: SQL server is reachable from my application as for the first time when i load the application, it retrieves all records from sql server and displays on the page. but when i make a change to sql server table(inserting a new record), notification not coming to page to refresh the newly added record on page.

Comment: if i am not able to connect to db server at all, how did i get the records retrieved and displayed on the page when my application loads for the first time?